# Can't get option page custom fields on custom taxonomy archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created options page using ACF and created custom taxonomy for posts and categories. I added to my header get_field for getting the logo and it's working fine on most of the page..

On the custom taxonomy category page i get no data.. I tried to var_dump
and print_r and whatever.. It just doesn't get anything and i couldn't find answer on Google..

Here are my codes-

**header.php**

```
    <?php
        if (get_field('konimhakol_logo', 'options')) {
            $site_logo = get_field('konimhakol_logo', 'options');
            echo '<a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'" title="'. get_bloginfo('name') .'"><img src="'. $site_logo['url'] .'" alt="'. $site_logo['title'] .'"></a>';
        }
    ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
function create_businesses_post_type() {
    register_post_type('kh_businesses',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('עסקים'),
                'singular_name' => __('עסק'),
                'add_new' => __('הוסף עסק')
            ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-home',
            'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'businesses'),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_businesses_post_type' );

// Add Businesses Post Type to Archives
function archives_add_custom_types($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_tag() && empty($query->query_vars['suppress_filters'])) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('kh_businesses'));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'archives_add_custom_types' );
```

This is my [Homepage](http://konimhakol.underconstruction.co.il/) and this is the [Archive page](http://konimhakol.underconstruction.co.il/%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9D/vehicles/)

I'm so frustrated.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your get_field() call should look like this:

```
get_field('konimhakol_logo', 'option')
```

You had 'options', but the documentation for ACF calls for 'option'

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/

Comment: Thanks, i just tried it now and i keep getting the same result

Comment: This is a clean underscores theme and i added the custom post type myself.. Maybe i missed something?

Comment: Custom post types and taxonomy archives should be irrelevant when calling custom fields on an options page. I use the get_field('', 'option') constantly, on all page templates and custom files, and i've never had any issues. Do you have any post types or taxonomies named 'option' or 'options' that could be causing a conflict?

Comment: Or, could your theme be utilizing 'option' or 'options' for some theme customization, and that could be causing a conflict.

Comment: This is my only custom post type (Businesses) and it's a clean Underscores theme. 

I have just noticed that when i go to nav-menus.php options screen there is only Businesses and their categories are under the regular WordPress categories

Comment: I tried now to search the entire theme folder for "option" but nothing found except for my code

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that theme, but get_field('FIELD_NAME', 'option') should work on any php file in your theme. Something is causing a conflict. I've checked a half-dozen sites I've built, and all of theme have no issue pulling custom fields from an options page, on standard page.php, taxonomy.php, single-[POST-TYPE].php, and everything pulls correctly.

Comment: There could also be a plugin causing a conflict. It might not be the theme.

Comment: I work alot with ACF but never had this problem before.. The logo shows on all pages except for my new custom post type.. 

Should i create archive-businesses.php?

Comment: I tried de-activating all plugins (had only 1 except for ACF) but nothing... I still think it's related to my functions.php code but not sure where to put my finger

Comment: Might as well try, but any file that calls your header.php should be able to display your custom field data. I just downloaded and installed the underscores theme on a test site, and my taxonomy-events.php file is displaying the data from an options page field without any problem.

Comment: Ok i tried but no change. I have also noticed that the menus aren't loading on this page so i tried deleting the get_field from header.php and still the menus don't show so i guess the problem is not related to the ACF but to my custom post type code

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the problem!
For getting the posts under the new categories i have added this code to my functions.php file-

```
// Add Businesses Post Type to Archives
function archives_add_custom_types($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_tag() && empty($query->query_vars['suppress_filters'])) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('kh_businesses'));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'archives_add_custom_types' );
```

But when i delete it, the header comes back but then there are no posts under my Business categories...

Comment: How can i add the the custom post type to my results page please?
I tried few codes i found on Google but nothing worked for me